# How to remove spaces from varchar in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to remove all spaces from column values of varchar2 type in an Oracle table. 
For example, `2012_2 psk` should become `2012_2psk`.

I've tried to `use REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '')` but it doesn't work. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: But `replace` does work !

Comment: In my case, REPLACE returns the same string that was passed in. Oracle 11g r2

Comment: what do you mean replace doesn't work? It certainly does work so you must be doing something else wrong. Please show how you use replace in your code.

Comment: SELECT replace(docnum), ' ', '') FROM tmp_uploadtable;

Comment: One suggestion. Values for DOCNUM column were imported from from Excel table. Is it possible that they contain some other hidden character that is shown as white-space when SELECT statement is executed?

Comment: I've found the solution. There are not whitespaces, there are some other symbols that show themselves as blank spaces. So next code is working fine:

SELECT regexp_replace(docnum, '\W','') FROM tmp_uploadtable;

Comment: Please show database definition of `docnum` and the length and value of the `docnum` that is not being modified. Show result from `SELECT docnum, replace(docnum, ' ', ''), LENGTH( docnum ) FROM tmp_uploadtable`. Also, note that your comment had invalid Oracle SQL syntax, so it couldn't work in that specific case.

Comment: Was going to suggest that maybe you are not looking at whitespace but you already found it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution. There are not white spaces, there are some other symbols that show themselves as blank spaces. So next code is working fine:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(docnum, '\W','') FROM tmp_uploadtable;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
regexp_replace(column_name, '[[:space:]]*','')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4424c/1)

Comment: I've tried this already. It also doesn't work :(

Comment: Which version of oracle?

Comment: 11G release 11.2. 64-bit edition

Comment: Ok... But it works in Oracle 11G R2.